# set a variable inside ajax function

Tags: ajax, variables

Why does the usernameOK=1; statement in the ajax function not stay set when I use the alert statement after the $.post function?  I need a way to use a variable as a condition for an if statement.

```
function validateRegistration() {
var username        = document.getElementById("userName").value;
var fname           = document.getElementById("fName").value;
var lname           = document.getElementById("lName").value;
var email           = document.getElementById("email").value;
var confirmEmail    = document.getElementById("confirmEmail").value;
var password        = document.getElementById("userpass").value;
var confirmPass     = document.getElementById("confirmPassword").value;
    var usernameOK = 0;

    $.post("action.php", { field: 'doesUsernameExist', username: username },  
    function(result){    //if the result is 1  
       if(result == 1){  //show that the username is available 
           usernameSuc.innerHTML= username + " is Available.";  
           var usernameOK=1;
        }else if(result == 0){  //show that the username is NOT available 
           usernameErr.innerHTML="User name: "+username+" is not  
           available.";             
        } else {
           usernameErr.innerHTML="Something is Wrong"; 
        }
    });  

    alert("usernameOK: "+usernameOK);  //This doesn't work. only prints a zero, never 1

    if (usernameOK == 1) {
       if ((username.length > 5) && (!(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/.test(username)))){
           if((fname != "") && (lname != "")){
               if((email != "") && (email == confirmEmail)){
                   if (((email.indexOf(".") > 0) && (email.indexOf("@") > 0)) 
                   && !/[^a-zA-Z0-9.@_-]/.test(email)){
                       if ((password.length > 7) && (/[a-z]/.test(password))
                       && (/[A-Z]/.test(password)) && (/[0-9]/.test(password))){
                           if (password == confirmPass) {

document.getElementById("submit").className = "btn btn-success";
document.getElementById("submit").removeAttribute("disabled");
                           }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
       }
  } else {
     document.getElementById("submit").className = "btn btn-success disabled";
  }

}
```

Comment: its because its an asynchronous request and happens after the alert.

Comment: Ok.  That would make sense for the way it is acting.  I am sure it is obvious, but I am learning Javascript/Ajax.  Do you know of a good example of how to make this work?  The Ajax works and returns the correct value, but because the 'usernameOK' value is not getting set to one it fails my usernameCheck function.  Is this by chance just simply a matter of where the code is placed?

Comment: Correction:  wrong function name in the previous comment.  the function is validateRegistration.  I added the remaining code to the whole function to my original post.  Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: think of an ajax call like a fork in perl or some other language. The calling context continues on and the ajax request executes in parallel. That's why if you move the alert to your ajax callback it will do as you expect. But outside, all bets are off, since you not in the callback context.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution.  Thought I would post it in case it would help someone else.  Changed the order and moved the ajax inside all the conditional if statements so it is the last thing to check instead of the first.

```
function validateRegistration() {
    var username        = document.getElementById("userName").value;
    var fname       = document.getElementById("fName").value;
    var lname       = document.getElementById("lName").value;
    var email       = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var confirmEmail    = document.getElementById("confirmEmail").value;
    var password        = document.getElementById("userpass").value;
    var confirmPass     = document.getElementById("confirmPassword").value;

    if ((username.length > 5) && (!(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/.test(username)))){
    if((fname != "") && (lname != "")){
        if((email != "") && (email == confirmEmail)){
            if (((email.indexOf(".") > 0) 
                               && (email.indexOf("@") > 0))    
                               && !/[^a-zA-Z0-9.@_-]/.test(email)){
                if ((password.length > 7) 
                                        && (/[a-z]/.test(password)) 
                                        && (/[A-Z]/.test(password)) 
                                        && (/[0-9]/.test(password))){
                    if (password == confirmPass) {

       $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "action.php",
      data: {field: 'doesUsernameExist', username: username },
      async: false,
      success: function (result) {
    if(result == 1) {
        document.getElementById("submit").className = "btn btn-success";
        document.getElementById("submit").removeAttribute("disabled");

            } else {
    document.getElementById("submit").className = "btn btn-success disabled";
    document.getElementById("submit").setAttribute('disabled', true);
    }
      },
      error: function (result) {
    pass = "error"
    alert("There was an error with the database");
      }                     
       });                          
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("submit").className = "btn btn-success disabled";
        document.getElementById("submit").setAttribute('disabled', true);
    }
```

}